# How to make a track collision in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, collision-detection

I'm having trouble to making a track border collide when the car rectangle hits it.
I tried using mask, but quite poorly and it didn't worked.

Here's the track border:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KnQCFyOpPSIFzlZ1nnyHNx27RiIVUs98/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I think you might have to just do a check on every movement of the car to see if the color of the track at the rectangle corners is the track color.

Comment: I took a screenshot and checked pixels by it. However on some places it shows black colour even thought it's gray (the track itself has gray within track).

Comment: The image that you posted has alpha value of `0` except for the border of the track, which has an alpha of `1` (or `255`, depending on you system). I think you could test for that.

Comment: What module should i use for this? I'm currently using kivy.core.Image for pixel reading, but it doesn't display alpha value.

Comment: How are you accessing the pixels. If you are using the `texture` of the `Image`, then the pixels are `RGBA`.